# Gitlab: artifact upload uses wrong URL

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running Gitlab on a development server running Ubuntu. I changed the config in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to an IP address.

I run my Gitlab pipeline and I always get

> Uploading artifacts... planfile: found 1 matching files
>   ERROR: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... error  error=couldn't
>   execute POST against
>   http://gitlab.example.be/api/v4/jobs/15/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive:
>   Post
>   http://gitlab.example.be/api/v4/jobs/15/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive:
>   dial tcp: lookup gitlab.example.be on 144.254.71.184:53: no such host
>   id=15 token=xhDJXFod WARNING: Retrying...
>   error=invalid argument

How come the artifact is using the DNS name and not the IP address while it is the IP address that is specified in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

This address is configured in your **Gitlab runner** configuration (`config.toml`).
This configuration file is different from your **Gitlab** configuration file.

```
[[runners]]
  url = "http://gitlab.example.be"
```

You can view all the advanced settings for your runner on the [Gitlab runner documentation page](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the same kind of issue I found this blog that saved my day: https://feiyang233.club/post/gitlab/ by adding

```
  [runners.docker]
      ...
      extra_hosts = ["FQDN:IP-addr"]
```

to the /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml file

Answer (score 0):

This was a real pain to sort...
But my solution is similar to @hootnot's (which didn't quite work for me but at least got me close).

I am running a Nginx reverse proxy with HTTPS and an OpnSense router with unbound DNS (an internal DNS server)

In the runner container:

When running `gitlab-runner register` I set the FQDN for my gitlab instance instead of the docker service name
e.g. https://gitlab.mydomain.com instead of e.g. http://gitlab

then modified the hosts file

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

And set the address for my reverse proxy host (Nginx Proxy Manager)

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.30.0.3      a5da90e0538c
172.18.0.6      a5da90e0538c
10.0.0.187 gitlab.mydomain.com
```

**/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml**

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "a5da90e0538c"
  url = "https://gitlab.mydomain.com"


       ...
```